# How to print a list with each element's index? - Python

Tags: python

still pretty new to Python and programming in general. My current task is to print each item of a list on separate lines with an index identifier in front of it. E.g. My list is currently:

```
['Ada Log\n', 'Ena Blue\n', 'Kin Wall\n', 'Kin Wall\n', 'Foxy Rex\n', 'Esk Brown']
```

I want this to output as...

```
[1] Ada Log

[2] Ena Blue

[3] Kin Wall

[4] Foxy Rex

[5] Esk Brown
```

So that the numbers 1-5 can be used as a further input to produce more information.
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: You seem to have accidentally deleted much relevant information. I undid that for you. Please do not remove info after getting an answer. The question is supposed to stay answerable without knowing "the" answer. (If I misunderstood you and the reason for the edit, please consider providing a summary for your edits, which point out the reason. That way I might understand better. The editor provides a field to write something for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension with enumeration:

```py
inp = ['Ada Log\n', 'Ena Blue\n', 'Kin Wall\n', 'Foxy Rex\n', 'Esk Brown']
output = ''.join(['[' + str(ind + 1) + '] ' + x  for ind, x in enumerate(inp)])
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[1] Ada Log
[2] Ena Blue
[3] Kin Wall
[4] Foxy Rex
[5] Esk Brown
```

Answer (score 3):

Mmm, `enumerate` should do the trick.

```
names = ['Ada Log\n', 'Ena Blue\n', 'Kin Wall\n', 'Kin Wall\n', 'Foxy Rex\n', 'Esk Brown']
#Note second argument in enumerate tells us where to start
for count,name in enumerate(names,1):
    print(f'[{count}] {name}')
```

output

```
[1] Ada Log

[2] Ena Blue

[3] Kin Wall

[4] Kin Wall

[5] Foxy Rex

[6] Esk Brown
```

Comment: Perfect, Thankyou!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you @Djpopple

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @BuddyBob's solution:

```
names = ['Ada Log\n', 'Ena Blue\n', 'Kin Wall\n', 'Kin Wall\n', 'Foxy Rex\n', 'Esk Brown']
for count,name in enumerate(names, 1):
    print(f'[{count}] {name}')
```